# Warning PHP oci_execute() and oci_fetch_row ()

Tags: php, oracle

I am tring to display in a php some columns from my database.
My PHP code looks like this:

```
<?PHP
$conn=oci_connect('student', 'STUDENT', 'localhost/XE');
if(!$conn)
{ $c=oci_error();
  trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
$stid=oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM matches m JOIN teams tt ON m.id_team1=tt.team_id JOIN teams ttt ON m.id_team2=ttt.team_id");
oci_execute($stid);
echo "<table>\n";
while (($row = oci_fetch_row($stid)) != false) {
   echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row[9] ."<td>".$row[4]."</td>"."<td>".$row[5]."</td>"."<td>".$row[13]."</td>";
   echo " </tr>";
}
echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

And I receive this error:

> `Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00911: invalid character in C:\Apache24\htdocs\finale.php on line 60   ( line 60= oci_execute($stid); )`
>
> `Warning: oci_fetch_row(): ORA-24374: define not done before fetch or execute and fetch in C:\Apache24\htdocs\finale.php on line 62  ( while (($row = oci_fetch_row($stid)) != false) )`

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: There doesn't look to be anything wrong with that SQL query. Have you tried copy-and-pasting it into a database query tool (e.g. SQL Developer) to see if it runs?

Comment: I removed the plsql tag. If you change the query with the simple `"SELECT * FROM matches"`, does it work fine? You may need to re-type your entire query, because an **invalid white space** might have been input  in there by mistake.

Answer (score -1):

in your code you may not join same table again ..
`"SELECT * FROM matches m JOIN teams tt ON m.id_team1=tt.team_id JOIN teams ttt ON m.id_team2=ttt.team_id"`

teams appeared twice.

Comment: Yes, because I want to do a self join